# A simpler way of getting single key and single value in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a more natural way of getting object's key and value in JavaScript?

I am trying to populate an array of object in my React App.

the data looks like:

```
Methods:[{"foo": "walk"}, {"bar":"run"}],

  getMethodList(){
    return this.state.Methods.map((item, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
        <input type="radio"
            name="Method"
            value={item.key}  <---Get the key of object
            onChange={this.handleMethodSelect}
        />
        {item.value} <---Get the value of the object
      </div>
    ))
  }
```

`Object.keys()` and `Objects.value()` returns a list of keys and values. Which is not somethign I want.

Is there a simple way of getting key and the value of objects in the similar fashion of other programming language(Python, Java)? If not, what is the best "Javascript" way of approaching my problem?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: I prefer to have state with fixed keys, so this issue never occurs: `[{"id":"foo","value":"walk"},{"id":"bar","value":"run"}]`.

Comment: @Shilly good call. Coming from other programming language like Python, getting key and value in JavaScript always annoys me. That seems to be a better approach

Comment: Using fixed keys is nice for consistency but if you can't control this, there is `Object.entries` as @ashishsingh pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ashish-singh suggested you should use `Object.entries`

```
Methods:[{"foo": "walk"}, {"bar":"run"}],

getMethodList(){
  return this.state.Methods.map((item, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
      <input type="radio"
        name="Method"
        value={Object.entries(item)[0][0]} 
        onChange={this.handleMethodSelect}
     />
     {Object.entries(item)[0][1]} 
    </div>
  ))
}
```

Let me say that this is an unusual way of using object, without knowing the key and using the key as a value.
Probably you should use something like this:

```
Methods:[{ key: "foo", value: "walk"}, { key: "bar", value:"run"}],

getMethodList(){
  return this.state.Methods.map((item, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
      <input type="radio"
        name="Method"
        value={item.key} 
        onChange={this.handleMethodSelect}
     />
     {item.value} 
    </div>
  ))
}
```